# Using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit prove that $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2+2x+1}=3/4$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit prove that
$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2+2x+1}=3/4$

Attempt:$|\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2+2x+1}-3/4|=|1/4\,{\frac { \left( x-1 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( x+1 \right) ^{2}}}|$ how to show that it is $<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-1|<\delta$ where $\delta=\delta(\epsilon)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2+2x+1}-\frac34\right|=\left|\frac{x^2-2x+1}{4(x^2+2x+1)}\right|=\frac{(x-1)^2}{4(x+1)^2}$$

For all $x\in[0,2]$, we have $(x+1)^2\ge1$, hence :

$$\left|\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2+2x+1}-\frac34\right|\le\frac{(x-1)^2}4$$

Given $\epsilon>0$, if we choose $x\in[0,2]$ such that $|x-1|\le\sqrt{4\epsilon}$, then :

$$\left|\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2+2x+1}-\frac34\right|\le\epsilon$$

In other words :

> $$|x-1|\le\min\{1,\sqrt{4\epsilon}\}\implies\left|\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2+2x+1}-\frac34\right|\le\epsilon$$

Comment: I am unable to understand how you get $\min\{1,\sqrt{4\epsilon}\}$. Can I write $|x-1|<\delta$ for $\delta=\sqrt{4\epsilon}$? Please elaborate the concept of usung min here, how 1 within $\min\{1,\sqrt{4\epsilon}\}$ comes?

Comment: @user1942348: For this kind of proof, we always have to find a *sufficient condition* of the form $|x-a|\le\delta$ that ensures $|f(x)-L|\le\epsilon$. What we have here is that, given $\epsilon>0$, it is sufficient that $|x-1|\le1$ *and* $|x-1|\le\sqrt{4\epsilon}$, to be sure that $|f(x)-\frac34|\le\epsilon$. But for every $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3$, the condition ($a\le b$ and $a\le c$) is equivalent to ($a\le\min\{b,c\}$).